# Compiling for windows on linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cross-compiling

Is it possible to compile a Win32 program on a Linux computer without the use of an emulator or Wine or anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836469/cross-platform-programming Here's some related info. You can install MinGW which lets you cross compile for Win32 on your Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

For more infomation, google "gcc crosscompile win32".

The first hit is [Building a Cross compiler for Windows on Linux](http://silmor.de/qtstuff.mingw.php)

Comment: Clearly we're interested in the same tags ;)

Comment: @heinrich5991: Broken link has been repaired (the original advice of searching for "gcc crosscompile win32" worked wonderfully to find the new URL)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure it is possible.
You have to use a cross-compiler toolchain. You can find a good gcc cross toolchain both for 32 and 64 bit targets at the following address http://www.drangon.org/mingw/

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, C++ was designed to compile the same code on multiple platforms, however take notice: if you have windows specific system calls/commands in your program they won't work on Linux and vice-versa.

Comment: This doesn't even come close to answering the question.

Comment: It wasn't meant to, the people that answered before me gave the answer. I just wanted to remark to the OP that if he has system calls he should convert those manually, it wouldn't compile otherwise on a different platform. Or maybe I just misunderstood the question. Anyway, I just hope my comment helped somehow.