# Cross compilation tutorials

Tags: c++, cross-platform, wxwidgets, cross-compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross platform programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836469/cross-platform-programming)

I've written some code using wxwidgets in c++. But I am not able to compile the same code for both windows and linux. Actually I'm a bit scared by the preprocessor directives generated by code-blocks ide. I wonder if anyone could point out some nice tutorials for learning cross-compilation.

Thanks in Advance

Jvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Cross Compiling wxWidgets Applications on Linux](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_wxWidgets_Applications_on_Linux) (Code::Blocks wiki) and  [Cross-Compiling Under Linux](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux) (wxWiki). There is also a section on cross compiling Windows applications in Brent W. Woodruff [C++ Introduction to wxWidgets](http://www.fprimex.com/coding/cpp-wx.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a cross platform program, you will stumbl across a few kind of problems.

**Cross compilers problem**

Some compilers are offering non-standard functionalities that might not work on other compiler. You have to make sure that compiler functionnalitie's you use are standard or available on all the compilers you use (An exemple would be the VC++ `#pragma` that wasn't usable on gcc until version  4.2.1)

**Platform specific functions and libraries**

Guess what, if you include `<windows.h>` it won't compile on a linux system (this is madness I know). So you must try to avoid those platform specific libraries/function. If you ever have to use them, try to encapsulate their use and select the specific class you need to compile on different system.

Here is a wonderful guide posted by the Mozilla foundation : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/C___Portability_Guide